# Proving Equivalence Relation on a set of functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Consider the set of functions from some set X $\rightarrow$ X. The relation fRg is defined by $$g = a^{-1} \circ f \circ a$$ for some function $a$ that is bijective from X $\rightarrow$ X.
I am wondering how to prove the equivalence relation, and to find the equivalence class for f(x) = x.

**Reflexive**: Look at $f(x) = a^{-1}(f(a(x)))$. Then take the bijective function $a(x) = x$, and clearly $f(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. So the relation is reflexive.

I'm having trouble proving the others. For example, with symmetry, I am unable to find a way to get from $g(x) = a^{-1}(f(a(x))) \Longrightarrow f(x) = a^{-1}(g(a(x)))$.

Comment: If $g = a^{-1}\circ f\circ a$, then $f = a\circ g\circ a^{-1}$. Can you prove transitivity?

Comment: My current efforts with transitivity have left me stuck; assume two relations fRg and gRh. Then I can write $h = a^{-1} \circ g \circ a$. Then replace the $g$ in this equation to get $h = a^{-1} \circ a^{-1} \circ f \circ a \circ a$, which does not give the result I hoped for since the function $a$ is there two times. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something important

Comment: Nope. The '$a$' connecting $h$ and $g$ might be another function than $a$, so you should give it another name, say $b$. Note furthermore that $(a\circ b)^{-1} = b^{-1}\circ a^{-1}$.

Comment: oh gosh, thanks for pointing that out. Using the property that you told me, I was able to get $(a \circ b)^{-1} \circ f \circ ( a \circ b)$ which corresponds to the what the relation needs.

Comment: Exactly! Well done!

Comment: I was able to understand and get the symmetric proof too. Although ended up getting $f = a \circ g \circ a^{-1} $like you said, does it matter if it doesn't match the form given in the beginning, with the inverse at the front (composition of functions isn't commutative)?

Comment: If you put $b=a^{-1}$, then $f = b^{-1}\circ g\circ b$, as desired. ;-)

Comment: Of course! Nice pointers, it's greatly appreciated

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Reflexive:$$ f=id f id^{-1} \implies fRf$$

Symmetric :$$f=a^{-1}ga \implies g=afa^{-1}$$

Transitive: $$f=a^{-1}ga$$,  and $$g=b^{-1}hb$$ then $$f=a^{-1}b^{-1}hba = (ba)^{-1}h (ba)$$

Comment: We got all that in the comments already.